# How to sum all positive values in Google Sheets based on whether the associated data in another column is unique

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet that my company is trying to transfer into Google Sheets from Excel. I've used an array formula to accomplish this result in Excel, but it's not translating to Sheets and I know very little about arrays in Sheets. Here is the data scenario:

In column A are names of clients. Some clients have multiple accounts and each account has a separate balance in my list of data, however, many clients have only one account. The client name appears in column A for every account they have in column B. So if they have three accounts, they appear three times in column A. The account names are in column B. The balances are in column C and can be either positive or negative depending on account activity from month to month.

I need to sum all *positive* balances for all clients with only *one* account. This will be workable by itself, but if I could also add all positive *net* balances for clients with *more than one* account as well, that would be ideal.

I need this formula to ensure that our *net* payments to clients, less the result of this formula, equals our total balance for all accounts for the month. Since we process *net* payments to our clients with more than one account, I can’t simply add up all positive balances. It has to be all positive balances for only those clients with one account. We have anywhere from 250 to 300 accounts to process each month, so being able to double check our balances is really helpful.

The formula that works in Excel (for just positive balances for owners with one account) is:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(D2:D350,(D2:D350>=0)*(COUNTIF(B2:B350,B2:B350)=1))}
```

If someone could help me out with a formula that will work in Sheets *and* explain a bit about how to convert the formula from Excel, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto the answer myself, but attached is a sample data sheet in case this helps anyone else with a similar need.

The trick was taking the ending row reference "350" out from all ranges.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-dxpI3GpLAxkoMyscPRsCwkaec1CWRuX5-5Ej0DjVTo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

To sum column A from row 1 to 10, but only if positive:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,">0")
```